Solving Three Coupled Differential Equations
I am a beginner in Mathematica. I want to solve the following coupled differential equations :
$$N_X^{'}=\sqrt3\frac{M_{pl}}{m_{\phi}^5}\frac{x^4}{\sqrt {xN_{\phi}+N_{\gamma}}}$$
$$N_{\phi}^{'}=-\sqrt3\frac{M_{pl}\Gamma_{\phi}}{m_{\phi}^2}\frac{xN_{\phi}}{\sqrt {xN_{\phi}+N_{\gamma}}}$$
$$N_{\gamma}^{'}=\sqrt3\frac{M_{pl}\Gamma_{\phi}}{m_{\phi}^2}\frac{x^2N_{\phi}}{\sqrt {xN_{\phi}+N_{\gamma}}}$$
The initial conditions are :
$$x=1,N_x=N_{\gamma}=0,N_{\phi}=1.03\times10^{10}$$
and the values of the constants are :
$$m_{\phi}=10^{13},\Gamma_{\phi}=10^5, M_{pl}=10^{19}$$
Can anyone help me how to solve these equations and get the plots for $N_{\phi}(x)$ ,$N_{\gamma}(x)\,\, vs\, x$ for the range of values $x\in (1,10^{11})$?

Welcome to Mathematica SE. There are many other questions that may help you write a solution. Please look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Coupled+differential+Equations for examples.

Please look at the documentation for NDSolve. There are many examples on how to use it. The first thing is of course to type your equations into Mathematica code ... After doing this, edit the question and include the code.

mt=10^13;gt=10^5;mpl=10^19; sol={nx[x],nt[x],ng[x]}/.NDSolve[{nx'[x]==Sqrt[3]mpl x^4/(mt^5 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), nt'[x]==Sqrt[3]mpl gt x nt[x]/(mt^2 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), ng'[x]==Sqrt[3]mpl gt x^2 nt[x]/(mt^2 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), nx[1]==0,ng[1]==0,nt[1]==103*10^8},{nx[x],nt[x],ng[x]},{x,1,10^11}]; Plot[sol[[1,1]],{x,1,10^11}] Plot[sol[[1,2]],{x,1,10^11}] Plot[sol[[1,3]],{x,1,10^11}] Put those three Plot on separate lines. Check all this VERY carefully before you trust any of this.

mt=10^13;gt=10^5;mpl=10^19; sol={nx[x],nt[x],ng[x]}/.NDSolve[{  nx'[x]==Sqrt[3]*mpl*x^4/(mt^5 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), nt'[x]==-Sqrt[3]*mpl*gt*x*nt[x]/(mt^2 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), ng'[x]==Sqrt[3]*mpl*gt*x^2*nt[x]/(mt^2 Sqrt[x nt[x]+ng[x]]), nx[1]==0,ng[1]==0,nt[1]==103*10^8},{nx[x],nt[x],ng[x]},{x,1,10^11}][[1]]; Plot[sol[[1]],{x,1,10^11},PlotRange->All] Plot[sol[[2]],{x,1,10^11},PlotRange->All] Plot[sol[[3]],{x,1,10^11},PlotRange->All] Leading - inserted. Put those three Plot on separate lines. Last two plots worry me. Check all this VERY carefully before you trust any of this.
